# Why will a random forest not outperform a regression tree?

Tags: random-forest, goodness-of-fit, cart

I have a training dataset with a binary response variable, 6 independent variables, and 21,000 observations.

I've fit both an ordinary regression tree and a random forest (mtry = 2, ntree = 2000) and there is almost no difference between the two when each model is validated, using RMSE and predicted to actual ratio as goodness of fit metrics.

Is this to be expected with a small number of independent variables, or am I not using the right metrics to measure goodness of fit?

Comment: Just a technical point but if your response is binary then it is performing classification not regression.

Comment: Are you evaluating your models using hold-out data or cross-validation/bootstrap?

Comment: Meadowlark- true, but the output I need is probabilities to be coded into lookup tables for actuarial software.

Comment: David- the final evaluation is done on holdout data.

Comment: RFs were introduced to deal with issues of overfitting in normal decision trees but this doesn't happen on every data set. More then the number of independent variables in depends on the number of possible splits that can be made with each variable and other things that can bias greedy decision tree learning and cause it to overfit.

Comment: Sounds good to me. You want to bump it up to a full answer?

Comment: There are a number of things that could be at play.  It might be a "easy problem" but it might involve a poorly set program.  To use 2k trees is a little crazy.  I find that 150 to 200 is sometimes overkill.  How deep are they.  Mtry might be a bit low.  They often exclude 25% or 30% of columns during fitting, not 75%.  Is your data a numeric or a boolean/factor?  Can you tell us anything about the dataset?  Can you show plot of RF convergence vs. number of trees?  How about variable importance plot when you don't specify mtry?

Answer (score 2):

Answered [in a comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105608/why-will-a-random-forest-not-outperform-a-regression-tree#comment206683_105608) by [Ryan Bressler](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/42703/ryan-bressler).

> RFs were introduced to deal with issues of overfitting in normal decision trees but this doesn't happen on every data set. More then the number of independent variables in depends on the number of possible splits that can be made with each variable and other things that can bias greedy decision tree learning and cause it to overfit. **– Ryan Bressler Jul 10 '14 at 4:00**. Distributed under a Creative Commons [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license.